# cakephp 2.1 migration cache error

Tags: cakephp, caching, migration, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to migrate my app from cakephp 2.0 to 2.1. I've been using 2.1 for a couple of weeks on my local development server, and everything works fine. I've just tried uploading to the production server, and I'm getting the error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found in app/Config/core.php on line 265
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't work out what. If anyone has experienced something similar or can offer any suggestions I'd be very grateful!

(I'm using the CakePHP 2.1.0 stable release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you very sure you uploaded all the "core" files (the `lib` directory)? It seems the `Cache` class is missing, which is a core class of CakePHP. The error message is indicating an incomplete CakePHP install on your server.

Verify if the file `lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php` exists and is readable by the webserver you are using (e.g. ownership is set to `apache.apache` or `www-data.www-data` and chmod is set properly. If using SELinux, also make sure the files have `httpd_sys_content_t` or `public_content_rw_t` context set).

Comment: Stupidly, I had set my FTP program not to upload files with name 'Cache', so the Cache directory wasn't getting uploaded. Needless to say I've disabled this setting. Thanks for much for helping me figure it out.

Comment: Explains as much :) Glad to be of help.